# undefined object when i load data from server in knockout

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, knockout.js

I load a list from server controller in knockout and receive that list correctly, also i print that, but when put this data in a multiple table html , there is an error that says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"...

But if i do that in a button function click, everything ok, but i need that without press any button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <tittle> <h1>Customers </h1></tittle>

    </head>

    <body>

        <button  data-bind="click: addItem">Add</button>
        <p>List Names:</p>
        <select multiple="multiple" height="8" data-bind="options:allItems"> </select>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/knockout-3.5.0.js"></script>
        <script src="/lib/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/prueba.js"></script>   

    </body>

</html>
```

this is the .js

```
function ViewModel(){

    this.allItems= ko.observableArray([]);
    var list=[];

    $.get("/customers", function(data) { 

        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            list[i]={name:data[i].name, lastname:data[i].lastname};
            alert(list[i].name);
            alert(list[i].lastname);
        }

        console.log(this.allItems); // here "allItems" is undefined
        this.allItems.push(list[0].name); //error
    });

    this.addItem= function(){

            console.log(this.allItems); // here "allItems" is not undefined
            this.allItems.push(list[0].name); //ok


    };

};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

so... i need push this list at the beginning , anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `this` in `get` method is not this `this` you think. You can assign `this` to `self` like `var self = this;` before `this.allItems = ko.observableArray([]);` and in your `get` method use `self.allItems` instead `this.allItems`.